# Prove that it is impossible to make 18

Tags: puzzle

Today, I was shown the following puzzle:

> Find a way to make the numbers $ 7 $ through $ 18 $ using any three adjacent numbers in the grid below:
>   \begin{array} {|c|c|}
> \hline
>  10 & 10 & 9 \\
> \hline
>  5 & 7 & 3 \\
> \hline
>  8 & 11 & 11 \\
> \hline
> \hline
> \end{array}
>
> Operations allowed: $ + $ $ - $ $ \div $ $ ( ) $. Parenthesis could be used for multiplication.
>
> Diagonal numbers aren't adjacent.
>
> Example: $ 15 = 11 + 11 - 7 $ (using numbers in an "L" shape from the bottom right corner)
>
> Because of the allowed operators, you can't do something like $ 12 = 5 + 7 + \frac{d}{dx} 3$

I was able to make all the numbers but 18. After half an hour of trying each combination, I was told that it was impossible to make 18.

Am I being told the truth? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the brackets for multiplication, like $(10)(10)(9)=900$?

Comment: @David Yes, parenthesis can be used for multiplication.  I'll update the question with adjacency rules

Comment: Since you didn't specify that we could only use each of those three numbers once, I'm going to say the answer is clearly $8+10\div 5 + 10\div 5 + 10\div 5 + 10\div 5 + 10\div 5$. ;b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't know how I would approch such a problem "mathematically" without running into a ton of cases. Anyways, [here](http://codepad.org/rHQkYCcv) is some code that checks in the *most unoptimized fashion* that there is no solution for $18$.

**Edit:** Not even [permuting the numbers](https://ideone.com/BADggB)

---

The weird indentation is because it didn't translate well from my editor, please don't blame me :).